# How to create Footer view in the table view Using View Controller in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, footer

I want to create a footer view in my table view.I have created view controller and add a subview as table view. So how can i add the footer view in that table view?.

Note: I have used only view controller, not table view controller.

I haven't used table view controller in my apps, bcoz i have used many controllers as subview in the view controller. Is there any sample programs available? So how can i achieve this?.

Please Help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your controller a table view delegate and use viewForFooterInSection method. For details,  check [UITableViewDelegate Protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW4).